# Django IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed even when trying to login into Admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've searched across a similar topics but did't find a solution for my particular case.
I have a `User` extended model and additionally `UserProfile` to extend and store some user's information.
`UserProfile` has a *`OneToOne`* relation to `User` model.
I've a `User` model `save` method overridden to instantly create a `UserProfile` object on `User` object created. But whenever I create a new `User` instance **`IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id`** raises even though both instances created successfully (User and UserProfile). After user created (even superuser) whenever I try to login into Django Admin I got the same **`IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id`**.

**I've tried** :

1. To apply migrations (just in case);
2. To delete database completely and repeat everything from a scratch;

I know theres is a way to change OneToOne relation to ForeignKey but I like to keep this kind  of relation if there is another solution.

**models.py:**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Please, provide a correct email.")
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if not kwargs.get('is_staff'):
        raise ValueError("Superuser must have 'is_staff' value set to True")

    if not kwargs.get('is_superuser'):
        raise ValueError("Superuser must have 'is_superuser' value set to True")

    if not kwargs.get('is_active'):
        raise ValueError("Superuser must have 'is_active' value set to True")
    return self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    """ Custom user model """

    objects = UserManager()

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)


class UserProfile(models.Model):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female')
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            "id",
            "password",
            "email",
            "profile_link",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at"
        )


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = "__all__"
```

And I'm not getting why the error points on this line on code **`UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)`** on login to Admin Panel. Why it keeps on performing `save` methond on login?

**UPDATE:**

If I delete a UserProfile object assigned to User tries to login - IntegrityError not rises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you login, Django update last_login fields and run save method. In this case your UserProfile create line raise an error.

My advice is don't create UserProfile on save method, you can use create signal for that [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/)

If you want to use your way, you can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: Thank you for a replay. Solve the problem with `get_or_create`. Work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Because when you login, Django update last_login fields and run save method.
> In this case your UserProfile create line raise an error.
>
> My advice is don't create UserProfile on save method, you can use
> create signal for that signals
>
> If you want to use your way, you can use get_or_create

If you prefer to use `get_or_create`, that would work fine but that would also trigger an unnecessary query on every login.

I would consider using it with a tiny improvement:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_create = not self.pk
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_create:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)
```